# Syntax error in a Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

```
SELECT itemID AS broID, 
       ittCode AS broField1, 
       ittDescr AS broField2, 
       itemCode AS broField3, 
       itemDesc AS broField4, 
       Qty AS broField5  
 FROM tblItem 
       INNER JOIN tblItemType ON (tblItem.itemiitID = tblItemType.ittID AND tblItem.itemProduct = true) 
       LEFT JOIN 
           (SELECT whiitemID,
                   Sum(whiQty) AS Qty   
              FROM tblWarehouseItem AS WI
                   INNER JOIN tblWarehouse AS W ON WI.whiwrhID = W.wrhID   
             WHERE w.wrhTemp = False        
               AND W.wrhActive = True    
               AND w.wrhLock = False     
          GROUP BY whiitemID) AS WItem ON tblItem.itemID = WItem.whiitemID 
ORDER BY ittCode, itemCode
```

When i try to run it i am getting a syntax error  if you please help me out 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
INNER JOIN tblItemType ON (tblItem.itemiitID = tblItemType.ittID AND tblItem.itemProduct = true)
```

to

```
INNER JOIN tblItemType ON tblItem.itemiitID = tblItemType.ittID AND tblItem.itemProduct = true
```

Comment: if i split my Query and run them separately they are working fine.

Comment: can you write the way you are creating sql in stirng? @emilios

Comment: if i understand correctly - I am running it from Access Queries . Not passing  it to a string yet

Answer (score 1):

thanks i solve it Changing the above line

```
(tblItem INNER JOIN tblItemType ON (tblItem.itemiitID = tblItemType.ittID AND tblItem.itemProduct = true))
```